# Create div transition like Spotify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I would like to have some help about the transition of a div in CSS or JavaScript.

I have a `<div>` with `dispay:none;`.
With some JS, i change the display option on `display:block`.
All is working correctly.

But i would like to know how to make a transition when the `<div>` appear on the screen.
Like the player [Spotify](https://www.spotify.com/us/) when you want to search something.

Thanks for you help.
And really sorry for my BAD english !

Comment: can you post a image of what you are looking for, or at least a description? i am not going to download the player, just to answer your question

Comment: Jacob : Its not a soft. And i can't take a picture of a transition.
On spotify : http://puu.sh/fMOp5/7234d6d1ad.png when you click on 'Rechercher' the right side appear with a transition. Like it was hidden at the left.

Comment: so, the search box and everything else slides in from the right?

Comment: From the left. From the left menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a JQuery like this:

```js
 $(function() {
     var open=false;
     $('.menubar span').click(function(){
         if(open==false){ 
             $('.search').css('left','50px');
             open=true;
         }
         else{
             $('.search').css('left','-100px');
         open=false;
         }
     });
 });
```

```css
.menu{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:50px;
    height:100%;
    background:#222021;
z-index:4;
}
.menubar{
    width:50px;
    height:100%;
color:white;
font-family:arial;
}
.search{
    position:absolute;
    left:-100px;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    background:lightgrey;
height:100%;   
        -o-transition:.3s;
-ms-transition:.3s;
-moz-transition:.3s ;
-webkit-transition:.3s;
transition:.3s  ;
}
.search input{
margin:0;
width:75px;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menubar">
    <span>Home</span>
  </div>

</div>  <div class="search"><input type="search"></div>
```

Click "Menu" in the menu bar, and the search bar slides out, click again to hide it.
To use JQuery, you have to include the jquery library:
include this in `<head>`:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Or download it from:http://jquery.com/download/
Then, just use the script like normal JS, in a `<script>` tag.
**EDIT:**
With your problem in the comments below, `#navbar` had a static position, which means z-index will not work for it:

```
#nav-bar {
    background-color: #23232C;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -17px;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i never use JQuery. Where i put the fonction ? In <script></script> ?

Comment: black text on black background?

Comment: @BrettCaswell its a example of the JQuery, not the CSS **styling**:)

Comment: @BrettCaswell Okay, I meant the style, not the transition, i am not gonna spend 5min making a pretty looking color scheme, when the OP doesn't care about the color scheme

Comment: Its working, thanks. Not really like on this site, but it's working :) thanks !

Comment: @nathanchevalier your welcome! :) just play with the script until you get it how you want

Comment: Hello, the transition is working perfectly on my website, but i have a problem :) the transition is over the left bar menu and not below (like your code). I don't found a solution with z-index.

Comment: @nathanchevalier set the bar menu to a z-index higher then the search menu, like `z-index:99 !important`  and inspect the menu with the inspector to see if you have overriding styles

Comment: Doesn't work ... I upload my files if you want to see : https://mega.co.nz/#!K01ACZRb!PLXLBQ2pre2WN8kGKZGv4sehPpWkpNp3LLIbJUGFsYw  I have CSS in the index.html and in css folder sorry

Comment: Can you post a link to the site? the file downloader is giving me trouble

Answer (score 0):

The following answers uses CSS Style Declarations to accomplish the transition effect.

if you declare the `transition: all 1s` style on an element. If the style property changes on that element your browser's (user-agent's) graphic device will calculate and update the frames (or visual changes) that occur between the two states (initial state, and end state). However, the property that is being changed must be scalar; that is, both the initial value and new value are scalar (like 0% being set to 100%). Additionally, if you're changing a property that is not scalar, but affects the rendering of other properties.. they will skip the transition effect (aka `display:none` being set to `display:block`).

Note: Instead of changing the inline style on the elements using **Javascript**, we're going to instead change the `class` of those elements; meaning, the following styles represent visual states, which we'll toggle between..

Again, the `transition` style declaration (or rather, the graphic device) will handle the incremental rendering of the frames between these two states.

---

### Code Sample of changing 4 style properties (explicitly)

```js
var str = 'hide';

var btn = document.querySelector("button#toggler").addEventListener('click', function(ev)
  {
     var elms = document.querySelectorAll('div.block');
     for (var i = 0, lng = elms.length; i < lng; i++)
     {
       elms[i].className = elms[i].className.replace("hide", "").replace("show", "").replace(" ", "");
       elms[i].className = elms[i].className + ' ' + str;
     }
     str = (str === 'show') ? str = 'hide' : 'show';
  });
```

```css
.block {
  display:block; position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;right:80%;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0);  
  border:0.1em solid black;
  min-width:5em;
  transition: left 2s, opacity 2s, right 2s, background-color 1s;
}

.wrapper 
{
  display:block;position:relative;background-color:whitesmoke;
  min-height:10em;
  width:auto;
  }


.show {opacity:1;left:0%;right:80%;background-color:rgb(255,0,0);}
.hide {opacity:0;left:80%;right:0%;background-color:rgb(0,0,255);}
```

```html
<button id="toggler">Toggle Block</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

---

The following is a fairly more complex slider, which ulitmately uses the same principal for rendering the transitions.

```js
$("div.slide > button.show" ).on('click', function (ev)
  {
    var slide = $(ev.target).closest(".slide");
    slide.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");    
    
    var slidePrev = slide.prev();
  
    slidePrev.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
    
    slidePrev = slidePrev.prev();
    
    slidePrev.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
  
    slidePrev = slidePrev.prev();
    
    slidePrev.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
  
    slidePrev = slidePrev.prev();
    
    slidePrev.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
  })

$("div.slide > button.hide" ).on('click', function (ev)
  {
   
    var slide = $(ev.target).closest(".slide");
    slide.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
  
    var slideNext = slide.next();
  
    slideNext.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
    
    slideNext = slideNext.next();
    
    slideNext.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
  
    slideNext = slideNext.next();
    
    slideNext.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
  
    slideNext = slideNext.next();
    
    slidePrev.toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
  
  })
```

```css
html, body {display:block;position:relative;margin:0 auto;padding:0;height:100%}

div.wrapper {position:relative;
  left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
  width:auto;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;  height:100%;
  }

button {line-height:2em;padding:0.2em;display:block;}



div.slide {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  border:0.2em solid black;
  background-color:white;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
  transition: left 1s, opacity 0.5s;
  }

div.slide:nth-child(1) {
  left: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
  }

div.slide:nth-child(2) {
  left: 3.5em;
  z-index: 2;
  }

div.slide:nth-child(3) {
  left: 6em;
  z-index: 3;
  }

div.slide:nth-child(4){
  left: 8.5em;
  z-index: 4;
  }

div.slide.hide {
  opacity:0.3;
  left: 59%;  
}

div.slide.show {  
  opacity:1;
  }

div.show > button.show {display:none;}
div.hide > button.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="slide show">
  
  <button class="show">show</button>
  <button class="hide">hide</button>
</div>

<div class="slide show">
  
  <button class="show">show</button>
  <button class="hide">hide</button>
</div>

<div class="slide show">
  
  <button class="show">show</button>
  <button class="hide">hide</button>
</div>

<div class="slide show">
  
  <button class="show">show</button>
  <button class="hide">hide</button>
</div>
</div>
```